# Result.Framework is not found in TrueTime?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using TrueTime library in my project.I downloaded it from below link

```
https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift
```

But when I opened it new project & choose `show in finder` I don't see any `Result.Framework` in finder. it is only in project structure.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The example code which you are using contain "Cartfile". So, you need to install carthage using below command,

```
$ carthage update
```

Or you can use "pod" in your code.

Comment: Even if I use pod it does not work.Should I use Carthage or pod in sample project

Comment: For sample, you are running need Carthage installation

Answer (score 0):

I actually installed pods for TrueTime in a separate project & from there i copied the Result file so that is how it worked.